# In bash, how do I define a "command scope" variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm reading this [book on the bash architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/bash.html) and one of the bash maintainers says:

> There are different variable scopes for shell function calls and **temporary scopes for variables set by assignment statements preceding a command**. When those assignment statements precede a command that is built into the shell, for instance, the shell has to keep track of the correct order in which to resolve variable references, and the linked scopes allow bash to do that.

I can't figure out how to do this.  This prints out a blank line:

```
foo="bar" echo $foo
```

This prints out "bar",
but the `foo` variable is still defined after the command finishes,
so I don't consider it to be "command scope":

```
foo="bar"; echo $foo
```

How do I define a variable with command scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first guess was right, but you used a bad example. 
When the shell reads the command

```
foo=bar echo $foo
```

the first thing it does (or, at least, one of the first things)
is to look for variable references (like `$foo`) and evaluate them. 
*Then* it processes what’s left of the line. 
(This may be a bit of an oversimplification;
see [`bash(1)`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/bash.1.php) or the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for details.) 
So you have the command

```
echo (nothing)
```

running with `foo=bar`; but it’s too late; there’s nothing left to look at the value of `$foo`. 
You can demonstrate this with the following sequence:

```
$ foo=oldvalue
$ foo=bar echo "$foo"
oldvalue
```

But

```
foo=bar command
```

is the way to go.  A couple of examples that work are:

```
foo=bar sh -c 'echo "$foo"'
```

and

```
foo=bar env
```

(You may want to pipe that through `grep foo`.)

I just now noticed the sentence that you quoted,
“When those assignment statements precede a command that is built into the shell, for instance, …”,
suggesting that built-in commands (such as `echo`) represent a special case. 
It is intuitive (to me, at least) that this “command scope” you’re looking for
would have to work by setting an environment variable in a child process,
and it’s not clear how it would work for a built-in command, which doesn’t run in a child process. 
Not many built-in commands access the environment directly,
and their interaction with shell variables is sometimes arcane. 
But I came up with a couple more examples that might be more what you’re looking for:

```
foo=bar eval 'echo $foo'
```

will display “bar”, because the evaluation of `$foo` is deferred. 
It is handled by the `eval` (built-in) command, rather than the shell’s initial parsing pass. 
Or, create a text file called (for instance) `showme.sh`. 
Put an `echo $foo` (or `echo "$foo"`) command into it, and say

```
foo=bar . showme.sh
```

This is probably what your book is talking about when it says,
“… the shell has to keep track of the correct order in which to resolve variable references ….” 
Somehow the shell runs the commands in `showme.sh` with `foo` equal to `bar`,
and then reverts to the previous value of `foo` (if any)
when it gets back to its primary input (the terminal).

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work because echo is a built-in command?  If so, I think you should emphasize that differently.  I'm not sure if that's the main takeaway.

Comment: No, I'm saying the same thing grawity is saying – it doesn't work because the `$foo` gets "expanded" before anything else happens. I updated my answer with more thoughts on built-in commands.

Comment: I recently had [a similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160189/27437) but learned it seems to be determined by whether the command explicitly uses variables passed from the environment (the parent process). `echo` does not. Whereas `env` and launching a new shell as in `bash -c '...` do.

Comment: @DocSalvager: That's what I was referring to when I said, "Not many built-in commands access the environment directly," but I guess I could have said it more clearly.

Comment: @G-Man; Why there is no variable expansion in `foo=bar sh -c 'echo "$foo"'` like `foo=bar echo "$foo"`?

Comment: Because variables are expanded inside double quotes (e.g., `"… $foo …"`) but not inside single quotes (e.g., `'… $foo …'`).  Since `echo "$foo"` is inside single quotes, that entire string gets passed to the new (``sh -c``) shell without being interpreted by the outer, interactive shell.

Comment: Then shouldn't `foo=bar echo '$foo'` work?

Comment: No, because the `echo` command is passed an argument that is four characters long: `$` `f` `o` `o`, and it echoes that.   (The fact that `echo` is a built-in command is irrelevant to this; you would get the exact same result if you specified `/bin/echo`, and `foo=bar ls -l '$foo'` would react similarly.)   These commands don’t treat `$` specially.   (Footnote: by comparison, `echo` sometimes treats ``\`` specially.)   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The difference is that when you say `foo=bar sh -c 'echo "$foo"'`, the program you are running is the shell — a second instance of the shell.  *That* shell is given the string `echo "$foo"`, and that new (secondary) shell *does* treat `$` specially, and *it* expands the `$foo` (which is only inside double quotes at this point) into the value of the `foo` environment variable.

Comment: *These commands don’t treat `$` specially.*: I didn't get that?

Comment: `echo '$foo'` outputs the string `$foo`. `cat '$foo'` and `ls -l '$foo’` look for a file called `$foo`. `grep '$foo' .bashrc` searches for the string `$foo` in your `.bashrc` file. But the shell, unlike those other programs, treats `$` specially; `sh -c '$foo'` looks for an environment variable called `foo`. For example, `foo=date sh -c '$foo'` will run a `date` command. (Compare to the fact that `cat '\0107'` and `ls -l '\0107’` look for a file called `\0107`, and `grep '\0107'` searches for the string `\0107`, but ``echo -e '\0107'`` outputs the string `G`, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  because ``echo`` treats ``\`` specially if the `-e` option is provided.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that variable expansion (`$foo` → value) happens before evaluating the entire command (put `foo=bar` to the environment, run `echo ...`).

It would work for commands that access the environment themselves:

```
foo=bar env | grep ^foo

foo=bar declare -p foo
```

Bash doesn't really have a proper scope for what you're looking; you will need to use the "subprocess" trick to get a new *process* for the command. (Of course it means the scope's read-only, *no* changes will reach the parent...) Use `( ... )` to create a subshell:

```
(foo=bar; echo $foo)
```